# Start process without stdout output

Tags: python

I am using a python script as a bootstrapper to start a long running java service.

```
call = [ "java", "-cp", ... ]

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as fnull:
    subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=fnull)
    print "Service started."
```

But when the python process has finished, I am still getting stdout output from the java process. I assume this is because python has shut my `fnull` so it reverts back to normal stdout.

How can I achieve what I want?

**EDIT:** On a side note, it would be nice to still get stderr if at all possible, but not if it adds any complexity.

**EDIT2:** It would appear that I am very much a moron, it was stderr that was being written to.

Comment: Are you sure that it's really `stdout` and not `stderr` you are seeing?

Comment: `stdout` points to `/dev/null`, you cannot be seeing it.  Your java process is probably sending messages to `stderr`.

Comment: Once the child process forks, it doesn't matter what happens to the parent file descriptor. The child gets /dev/null. Add my vote to the stderr hypothesis.

Comment: Yep - I'm a moron, it was stderr that was being written to. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to the side note, its easy to get stderr (its more complex when you want both stdout and stderr). It has the added advantage that it will tell you whether the java output you think is on stdout is really on stderr.

```
call = [ "java", "-cp", ... ]

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as fnull:
    subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=fnull, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print "Service started."
for line in stderr:
    print 'stderr: ', line.strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are okay with letting the python script live

> Popen.communicate(input=None)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

Comment: `communicate()` only captures stdout and stderr if they're directed to `popen.PIPE`, which isn't the case here.